# Stripe payment intent remains incomplete with 3D Secure

Tags: javascript, java, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement 3D Secure in my web app. It works perfectly well with a SEPA debit and a card debit that doesn't need 3D Secure. However, with a card that requires 3D Secure, the payment remains in the `Incomplete` state in Stripe dashboard.

My product is an annual subscription.

First I create a payment intent on the server (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) and I send the client secret in the HTTP response.

```java
List<Object> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
paymentMethodTypes.add("sepa_debit");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("amount", 2000);
params.put("currency", "eur");
params.put(
  "payment_method_types",
  paymentMethodTypes
);

PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(params);
```

After that, I use `stripe.confirmCardSetup` on the frontend with the `clientSecret` and with the `card` element and I send the payment method to my backend.

```js
const response = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
    }
})

await setDefaultPaymentMethod(payload?.setupIntent?.payment_method);
```

Then I retrieve the payment method and attach it to the customer and I finally create the subscription as shown in Stripe examples (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/examples).

```java
PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod.retrieve(
    "pm_***"
  );

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(
  "customer",
  "clg_***"
);

PaymentMethod updatedPaymentMethod = paymentMethod.attach(params);


// Create subscription
```

It does display the 3D Secure authentication modal on the frontend. However, at the end of the whole process (after creating the subscription on the backend), card payment that requires 3D Secure remains in `Incomplete` state. Can anyone point me to the right direction to implement 3D Secure correctly?

[image: enter Subscription in Incomplete state]

Answer (score 2):

Which test card are you using to test your integration? For instance the `4000 0027 6000 3184` card will require 3DS confirmation regardless of whether the card was previously set up using a SetupIntent. You probably want to use the `4000 0025 0000 3155` card to [test SetupIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards).

Saying that, SetupIntents in this scenario are usually only used for subscriptions that have a trial period. The idea being that you authenticate the card now so it can be charged at a later date without requiring 3DS authorisation. If you are creating subscriptions without a trial period, then you should [create the subscription with the payment method and handle any 3DS actions if required](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription) while your user is "on-session".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using the card you mention (`4000 0025 0000 3155`). The thing is I would like to charge later because I am processing some data the client sends to the server, and I only want to charge the customer if the process succeeds. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks! Seems some test-cards set `requires_action` status, although customer and/or `Stripe.js` **did already once complete the SCA/3DS** (for SetupIntent).

Comment: Even for first Invoice. Now, I wonder if that is only for test-purposes, or would any real-world card ever behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating subscriptions without a customer session, remember to include `off_session: true`, when creating the subscription:

Example:

```js
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customerId,
    off_session : true,
    items: [
        { price: priceId }, 
    ],
});
```

Comment: Wrong, that was already set and I am searching here for answers.